# numpy.linalg.inv returns inverse for a singular matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-inverse, singular

The matrix below is singular, and AFAIK attempting to invert it should result in

```
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

but instead, I do get some output matrix. Note that output matrix is a non-sensical result, because it has a row of 0's (which is impossible, since an inverse of a matrix should itself be invertible)!

Am I missing something here related to floating point precision, or the computation of a pseudoinverse as opposed to a true inverse?

````
$ np.__version__ 
'1.13.1'
$ np.linalg.inv(np.array([[2,7,7],[7,7,7],[8,7,7]]))
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  3.43131400e+15,  -2.05878840e+16,   1.71565700e+16],
       [ -3.43131400e+15,   2.05878840e+16,  -1.71565700e+16]])```
````

Comment: I get `numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix` (numpy 1.11.3).

Answer (score 7):

Behind the scenes, NumPy and SciPy (and many other software) fall back to LAPACK implementations (or C translations) of linear equation solvers (in this case `GESV`).

Since `GESV` first performs a LU decomposition and then checks the diagonal of `U` matrix for exact zeros, it is very difficult to hit perfect zeros in the decompositions. That's why you don't get a singular matrix error.

Apart from that you should never ever invert a matrix if you are multiplying with other matrices but instead solve for `AX=B`.

In SciPy since version 0.19, `scipy.linalg.solve` uses the "expert" driver `GESVX` of `GESV` which also reports back condition number and a warning is emitted. This is similar to matlab behavior in case the singularity is missed.

```
In [7]: sp.linalg.solve(np.array([[2,7,7],[7,7,7],[8,7,7]]), np.eye(3))
...\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py:223: RuntimeWarning: scipy.linalg.solve
Ill-conditioned matrix detected. Result is not guaranteed to be accurate.
Reciprocal condition number: 1.1564823173178713e-18
  ' condition number: {}'.format(rcond), RuntimeWarning)
Out[7]: 
array([[  0.00000000e+00,  -1.00000000e+00,   1.50000000e+00],
       [  3.43131400e+15,  -2.05878840e+16,   1.71565700e+16],
       [ -3.43131400e+15,   2.05878840e+16,  -1.71565700e+16]])
```

Answer (score 3):

One note from the numpy team:

> The de-facto convention in the field is that errors in matrix
>   inversion are mostly silently ignored --- it is assumed that the user
>   knows if this is something that needs to be checked for (implying that
>   a more controlled approximate inversion method needs to be used ---
>   the regularization is problem-dependent).

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2074

Seems to give an error on 1.13.0 however

Comment: Very relevant, thanks. Based on that thread, it does sound like a precision-related issue, though that makes me wonder under what circumstances numpy will successfully detect a singular matrix, and why this specific (and small) matrix fails...